# How to host Asp.net website with SQL Server database on server (personal Laptop)

Tags: asp.net, iis, webserver

I have website which was developed in ASP.NET, I want to host this website on a server which is my own laptop (for test purposes). Also the website has interaction with SQL Server. So then anybody can use this website when my laptop is turned on. Is it possible? If yes, please inform me of the correct way to host my website

Comment: This can be done but  you need to have a static ip for laptop.

Comment: @arun- Ok, No problem, I will be keep static ip only. what else requirement and what are the steps required to be follow?

Comment: You just have to install IIS on your PC and use it as a web server. Your site will be available by IP or domain name https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323972. Also you can use dynamic IP and domain name with Dynamic DNS service like http://dyn.com/

Comment: @feeeper- I dont want to localhost. still I need IIS?

Comment: @d0812 Yes. When you host website on IIS your site will be available by IP address.

Comment: ok. It is already installed on my laptop

Comment: @feeeper, - I read on google , there is software available to host PHP website. like wamp, xampp. also somethig set firewall off. like. Is it related to that?

Comment: Nope. ASP.NET (v.4 and below) websites possible host only on IIS

Comment: @ if ASP.Net version is 4.5 then?

Comment: @d0812 ASP.NET 5 only can be hosted not only on IIS now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to install IIS on your PC and use it as a web server. Your site will be available by IP or domain name ([how-to](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323972) or [Youtube how-to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwbKquNBNgQ)). Also you can use dynamic IP and domain name with Dynamic DNS service like dyn.com

Comment: If I host website by using IIS only then I need to installed IIS on other laptop as well to see website?

Comment: @d0812 What you mean "see website"? Use it for (1) update/deploy website and other development needs or (2) open it in the browser? So for (1) option - yes you'll need IIS on the other development PCs. For (2) - no, you don't need IIS on the client PCs.

Comment: "See website" means there is interaction with database so, client can add,edit ,update data on website (in some webpage). is it possible without IIS installation on client PC?

Comment: @d0812 Yes, sure. IIS is not required for that.

Comment: @feeeper- tons of thanks!! to clear my basic concepts. I can host my website on IIS and it works on my laptop properly,but I'm not able to see same website from my friends laptop browser,link  is like "http://localhost/websitename/Home.aspx"

Comment: You have to use your IP address instead of localhost: http://<ip-address>/websitename/Home.aspx

Comment: by using IP address in link it return error that `Network Error (tcp_error) A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out" The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.` Internet working properly

Comment: @feeeper- Tons of thansk Once again!!!....its working properly. the problem is with that firwall settings